# How to join CodeIgniter to existing project which doesn't use CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new in the web development.
I created a username/password page using CodeIgniter.
Now I have to join my work to another website which doesn't use the MVC structure.
I read an article talking about what Codeigniter cannot do here:

https://philsturgeon.uk/codeigniter/2012/12/05/5-things-codeigniter-cannot-do-without-a-rewrite/

and I didn't find anything about join a Codeigniter project to another website. 
However, I didn't find any tutorial which explain how can I add a Codeigniter project to a "no-MVC" structure....Or maybe they didn't mentioned it in the article I sent you but it's actually impossible to do it..

So, assuming that it's possible to join a Codeigniter project. I currently have access to my login/password page using this url

```
http://localhost:8888/CodeIgniter-3.0.0/index.php/login
```

On my website, I want to create a link which redirect to my login password.
I put on on my CodeIgniter file as follow

```
root:
   -System /
   -Application /
   -public_HTML /
        -> index.php (from CodeIgniter)
        -> asset/
        -> index.html
```

Now I want to create a link into my index.html which redirect to the Login page which is store into /Application/controller/Login.php. In localhost I don't have this problem because I need to write in the url:

```
index.php/class_name/method_name
```

Given I had no idea about how to redirect to my login page, I tried to create a link by this way (which didn't work as you might guess)

```
 <a href="../Application/controller/Login.php">Contact</a>
```

I don't really have an idea about how to id so please, does anyone can explain me how can I join a CodeIgniter project to another one which doesn't use a MVC structure.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You may try to take out the ***public_html*** folder from the Codeigniter (CI) folder structure, this because CI uses ***index.php*** to load your CI application.

```
(root_folder)/
    -> /ci_folder/index.php
    -> /ci_folder/application/
    -> /ci_folder/system/
    -> /public_html/
```

After that create the link with the URL to **/public_html/index.html**

Answer (score 0):

it's working now.
I just load the index.php/Login from the index.html :)
I juste didn't understand that CI uses index.php to load CI application !